# What is different between the regular version of Ultima 8 and the Gold Edition?

Tags: ultima-8

Good Old Games is selling [*Ultima 8: Gold Edition*](http://www.gog.com/game/ultima_8_gold_edition). However, it doesn't say what is different about that version and the original version of *Ultima VIII: Pagan* that was originally released. Usually a Gold Edition means that expansion packs are included, but no expansions were created ([*The Lost Vale*](http://ultima.wikia.com/wiki/Ultima_VIII:_The_Lost_Vale) was canceled).

What is different between the regular version of Ultima VIII and the Gold Edition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It includes the Speech Pack, which adds voices for the Titans & some other character (e.g. Khumash-Gor and the Zealan Gods).

I think the only version of U8 that did not include the Speech Pack was the original release on floppy discs, which is much harder to find now. For that version the Speech Pack was sold separately.

There was also a major patch for U8 after both the initial floppy and CD-Rom release.

Major changes included more tolerance when placing reagents for sorcery, improved jumping controls and unlimited changes for the only quick travel teleport item in the game. When I consider how much trouble I still have with that, it is a miracle I managed to play through the unpatched version. Fortunately, I did not run out of charges for the teleport item, otherwise I would have given up.

You can find the complete patch notes [here](http://www.pdragon.net/u8/u8patch.txt). As a historical note, this is the first time that a Ultima game received a major patch like this, which was distributed by computer magazines and online.

Unsurprisingly, that patch is included in the gold version as well.

Comment: I seem to remember at some point they added something to make jumping better. Rather than jumping a fixed distance in a direction you could jump to where the cursor was... I guess that must have been in that speech pack too...

Comment: No, that was a major patch and came a bit later. Maybe I will include this in my answer as well...

Comment: I was aware of the major patch, but figured that the patch alone wouldn't make the game a "Gold Edition". So I think the main point here is the inclusion of the Speech Pack.